# How do I get the unique id for checkboxes in a repeater?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My repeater is in a user control and uses an asp:repeater. Here is my code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrNotOnFile" Runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>      
            <tr>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>Item <asp:Label ID="NotOnFileItemNumber" Runat="server" />:
                   <asp:Label ID="lblPartNumberNotOnFile" Runat="server" />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <asp:Checkbox id="chkPartSelected" runat="server" onClick="isSamChecked()"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <asp:Checkbox id="chkPartWatchParts" runat="server"/>
               </td>               
               <td>
                   <asp:Checkbox id="samSelected" runat="server" onClick="isMbChecked()"/>
                                   </td>               
            </tr>   
        </ItemTemplate>        
    </asp:Repeater>
```

The checkboxes chkPartSelected and samSelected are in each repeater item and I am trying to uncheck one when the other is checked and vice versa.

Here's my jquery functions:

```
<script>
 function isMbChecked() {


         if ($('#ResultsNotOnFile_rptrNotOnFile_ctl01_chkPartSelected').is(":checked"))

             ($('#ResultsNotOnFile_rptrNotOnFile_ctl01_chkPartSelected').prop("checked", false))


     }
     function isSamChecked() {

               if ($('#ResultsNotOnFile_rptrNotOnFile_ctl01_samSelected').is(":checked"))

                   ($('#ResultsNotOnFile_rptrNotOnFile_ctl01_samSelected').prop("checked", false))

     }
</script>
```

These function work when I hard code the unique id for each checkbox in the repeater, but I do not want it hardcoded because I can have one or many repeater items.

How do I get that unique id and pass it to the  functions?

Thanks for any help

JGraham

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would just ditched the IDs since they aren't unique, and add some classes to these to make them more identifiable.

e.g.

```
<asp:Checkbox runat="server" class="sam" onClick="isSamChecked()"/>
<asp:Checkbox runat="server" class="mb" onClick="isMbChecked()"/>
```

Then you could do something like

```
<script>
 function isMbChecked() {
   var closest = $(this).parent('td').siblings().children('.sam');
   closest.prop('checked', !closest.prop('checked'));
 }

 function isSamChecked() {
   var closest = $(this).parent('td').siblings().children('.mb');
   closest.prop('checked', !closest.prop('checked'));
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could not make this work for me. I am new to JS and JQ so I may have done something wrong.

Comment: @JGraham Just noticed a mistake I had made. Check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, then onclick functions can be replaced with jQuery selectors as below. uncheck all checkboxes first and then check only the checkbox that is clicked using this (points to clicked checkbox element) keyword inside the jQuery click function.
If repeater has unique id then below selector can be used.

```
$('#rptrNotOnFile Checkbox[id="chkPartSelected"]').click (function() {

    $('checkbox').attr('checked',false);

    this.attr('checked',true);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 examples of how to get the ID's. The first is pure javascript. The second snippet uses jQuery and needs a couple of modifications on the .aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isChecked(element) {
        //set the checkbox names as fixed variables
        var checkbox1_name = "chkPartSelected";
        var checkbox2_name = "samSelected";

        //new variables for the id's to be found
        var checkbox1_id = "";
        var checkbox2_id = "";

        //split the id of element
        //looks something like this: mainContentPane_rptrNotOnFile_chkPartWatchParts_0
        var idArray = element.id.split('_');

        //loop all the items in the array to build the id's
        for (var i = 0; i < (idArray.length - 2) ; i++) {
            checkbox1_id += idArray[i] + "_";
            checkbox2_id += idArray[i] + "_";
        }

        //add the checkbox names and the last item of the array
        checkbox1_id += checkbox1_name + "_" + idArray[idArray.length - 1];
        checkbox2_id += checkbox2_name + "_" + idArray[idArray.length - 1];

        //set both checkboxed to unchecked
        document.getElementById(checkbox1_id).checked = false;
        document.getElementById(checkbox2_id).checked = false;

        //check the checkbox that was clicked
        element.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

For this first example to work just change `onClick="isSamChecked()"` to `onClick="isChecked(this)"`

In this second example we'll be using the row number of the repeater to find the ID's of the checkboxes.

First add an ID to the table surrounding the repeater `<table id="rptrNotOnFile_table">` since a Repeater does not add it's ID to the page we have to add one manually.
Then the row number as attribute of TR in the template `<tr rownumber="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>">`.
No event on the checkboxes itself `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkPartSelected" runat="server" />`.

And finally the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //bind a click function to the checkboxes in the table
        $("#rptrNotOnFile_table input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
            //find the row number from the attribute of the above tr
            var rowNumber = $(this).closest('tr').attr("rowNumber");

            //the function bound to the click on the checkboxes
            isChecked(rowNumber)

            //check the checkbox that was clicked
            this.checked = true;
        })
    });

    function isChecked(rowNumber) {
        //set the id of the repeater as fixed variable
        var repeater_id = "<%= rptrNotOnFile.ClientID %>";

        //set the checkbox names as fixed variables
        var checkbox1_name = "chkPartSelected";
        var checkbox2_name = "samSelected";

        //new variables for the id's to be found
        var checkbox1_id = repeater_id + "_" + checkbox1_name + "_" + rowNumber;
        var checkbox2_id = repeater_id + "_" + checkbox2_name + "_" + rowNumber;

        //set both checkboxed to unchecked
        document.getElementById(checkbox1_id).checked = false;
        document.getElementById(checkbox2_id).checked = false;
    }
</script>
```

You could probably do this much simpler, like the other 2 answers show. But since the question was to also get the ID's from a asp.net element that repeats data (ListView, GridView, Repeater etc) I've provided this rather extensive answer.